# Getting latest datetime from a splist

Tags: development, splistitem, splist, date-time

I have sharepoint list with data and one of the columns contains date ... how can i programmatically retrieve the latest date, the field is a Date And Time type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order by the column (descending), then set the query's rowlimit to 1:

```
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="YourColumn" Ascending="FALSE" />
</OrderBy>
```

From here: [SO: MAX query using CAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520927/180312)

Answer (score -1):

You can use foreach loop against your list's date column and then compare it with datetime.now to get latest date.